# Why can't I initialize or make a request with SessionManager in Alamofire 4.0? (UPDATED)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Migrating to `Alamofire 4` and I am trying to initialize a session manager like so:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["MyCompany-User-Agent": Config.MyCompanyUserAgentDataString]
var alamoManager: SessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

However I keep getting the error as

> Cannot invoke SessionManager with an argument list of
>   type(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration)

I am following the syntax at https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#modifying-the-session-configuration, but mine has errors. What am I doing wrong here? Also I can't do a request from the `SessionManager`.

**For example:**

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<MyCustomResponse>) in
            if let result = response.result.value {} }
```

Works with **no** issues, **BUT** (where alamoManager is a SessionManager):

```
alamoManager.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<MyCustomResponse>) in
            if let result = response.result.value {} }
```

It doesn't work. I get the error as

> Value of type SessionManager has no member request

Very confused as to why I am getting that error. The docs clearly show an example of a `SessionManager` object using a request method.

I have noticed though that there are no issues with this code if I create a **new** project. However in my existing project these errors display. I have checked the `Podfile.lock` and the version of `Alamofire` is indeed 4.0. I have build settings to target iOS9.0 for all targets and the project.

Could someone help me with this please? Tearing my hair out a bit!

Comment: Both of your code snippets compile for me in XC 8 GM with AF 4.0.0 (if I paste in the `responseObject` implementation from the AF docs, that is). You may have to give a more complete case to let others reproduce the error.

Comment: So the first snippet. Even if I create a new class in my existing project I still get the error Cannot invoke SessionManager with an argument list of type(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration. But in a new project I don't get that...wonder if it's the build settings or something..

Comment: @Kex any updates u got?

Comment: This works for me as well if you don't try to the session manager global. If you make it global I see the same error. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you initialize the extra headers with Alamofire's default Headers:

```
    // Adding Headers:
var defaultHeaders = Alamofire.SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
defaultHeaders["MyCompany-User-Agent"] = Config.MyCompanyUserAgentDataString
    // adding Configuration:
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = defaultHeaders 
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
var alamoManager: SessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```